# python: installing matplotlib locally

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, installation

I am a user without root privileges on a linux multi-user platform. I would like to install `matplotlib` (I have seen some questions on stackoverflow but they are old and related to previous versions of matplotlib). I think the thing I should do is installing from source `python -mpip install .`. I cannot find any way to install locally and not globally, as I don't have superuser privilege.

Comment: Can you install `conda` as a user then use `conda` environments to install `matplotlib`?

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look [here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/2987/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-do-a-user-local-install-of-a-python-package), on stackexchange the problem were solved.

As you can read:

- Download the matplotlib and install it manually
- install it using pip or easy_install

**Manually**:

```
cd /dir/of/your/downloaded/lib
python setup.py install --user
```

**With pip or easy_install**:

```
pip install --user matplotlib
easy_install --prefix=$HOME/.local/ matplotlib
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have `pyenv` installed on the system you can easily switch to another python environment that has matplotlib installed.

For example, you can install the latest version of anaconda python, using tab key autocompletion to see which versions are available.

```
pyenv install anaconda3-5.2.0
```

Then you can switch your local python version using

```
pyenv local anaconda3-5.2.0
```

Now you can check your python version and matplotlib should be available.

On the other hand if `pyenv` is not currently installed, either ask your admin to install it or use a workaround [script](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv-installer) as described [here](https://amaral.northwestern.edu/resources/guides/pyenv-tutorial).